# Java: File output help

Tags: java

Fixed:  Instead of calling isFile() I used exists() and it seems to be working fine.  If possible could someone explain why this change worked?

I'm attempting to write out to an excel file but am having a problem when trying to create that file if the name already exists.

Basically I am taking a file that is uploaded to a server, reading it, and then outputting a report file in a new location with the same filename.  I tried to do this by simply checking if the file already existed and then adding a number onto the filename.  My code works if the file doesn't exist or if it exists without a number (e.g. filename.xls).  If a file exists with the name "filename1.xls" the server just seems to hang when trying to write the file.  What can do to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
        String destination = "c:/apache-tomcat-7.0.8/webapps/reports/" + fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1, fileName.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".xls";
        int filenum = 1;
        while (new File(destination).isFile()) {
            destination = "c:/apache-tomcat-7.0.8/webapps/reports/" + fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1, fileName.lastIndexOf(".")) + filenum + ".xls";
            filenum++;
        }
        WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(destination));
```

Answer (score 2):

That will happen if some process is still keeping the file open. E.g. you've created a `FileInputStream` on the file to read it, but are never calling `close()` on it after reading.

---

**Unrelated** to the problem, the expanded WAR folder is not the best place to use as a permanent storage. All those files in the expanded WAR folder will get lost whenever you redeploy the WAR. Also hardcoding a servletcontainer-specific path in the code makes it totally unportable.

If your *actual* intent is to return the Excel file on a per-request basis to the client using a servlet, then you should be using

```
WritableWorkbook workBook = Workbook.createWorkbook(response.getOutputStream());
// ...
```

This way it writes to the response immediately without the need for an intermediate file.

Comment: If something was still keeping the file open then why would if work if a file with the name "file.xls" but not with the name "file1.xls".  Wouldn't it fail in both situations?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix, directory)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) API:

```
String localName = new File(fileName).getName();
String nameNoExt = localName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
String extension = localName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")); // need to include the .
File directory = new File("c:/apache-tomcat-7.0.8/webapps/reports/");
File destFile = File.createTempFile(nameNoExt, extension, directory)
```